# Debugging a stripped ARM binary

Tags: objective-c, gdb, arm, reverse-engineering

I've disassembled a stripped ARM binary with [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) and found the address of a method I'm interested in, 0x00065414. However, when connecting to the running app with gdb all addresses start from a base address that I cannot figure out. How can I determine my running applications base address (Entry Point?) in gdb?

#### Notes

- The binary's FairPlay DRM was removed using [Clutch](https://github.com/KJCracks/Clutch)
- ASLR was removed by clearing the PIE header flag using [a python script](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/build/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py)
- Verified changes using otool

#### GDB setup

```
$ gdb ./MyApplication
(gdb) attach -waitfor MyApplication
```

Start App and it pauses immediately at launch.

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x3bbcdb88 in <redacted> ()
#1  0x3bbbc8fc in <redacted> ()
#2  0x3bbc4130 in <redacted> ()
#3  0x3bbc4014 in ccpbkdf2_hmac ()
#4  0x3bb9f9d0 in CCKeyDerivationPBKDF ()
#5  0x0015b750 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#6  0x0015ca46 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#7  0x0015c69c in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#8  0x0015b4d0 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#9  0x0015c110 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#10 0x0001695a in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#11 0x000ba256 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#12 0x00017bde in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#13 0x33b9eaac in <redacted> ()
#14 0x33b9e4f2 in <redacted> ()
#15 0x33b98b40 in <redacted> ()
#16 0x33b33a06 in <redacted> ()
#17 0x33b32cfc in <redacted> ()
#18 0x33b98320 in <redacted> ()
#19 0x3601876c in <redacted> ()
#20 0x36018356 in <redacted> ()
#21 0x31374776 in <redacted> ()
#22 0x31374712 in <redacted> ()
#23 0x31372ede in <redacted> ()
#24 0x312dd470 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#25 0x312dd252 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#26 0x33b975c2 in <redacted> ()
#27 0x33b92844 in UIApplicationMain ()
#28 0x0001aaf2 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
#29 0x00009028 in dyld_stub_pthread_key_create ()
```

Checking various locations for expected instructions so I can set a breakpoint:

```
(gdb) disas 0x65414
No function contains specified address.
```

I assume that the correct location is some  + 0x65414. So I tried 0x33b92844 which is UIApplicationMain as the base.

```
(gdb) disas 0x33BF7C58
Dump of assembler code for function <redacted>:
0x33bf7934 <<redacted>+0>:  f0 b5                         push  {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
```

This address is definitely in the land of redacted or symbol stripped code, but the address doesn't land you on a procedure boundary. So it isn't the right place.

Comment: disassemble the binary.

Comment: @dwelch The binary has been disassembled using Hopper. The address space is definitely different than at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a :

```
starti
```

It let you enter in your dynamic linker (if your binary id dynamically linked) which will call the __libc_start_main function and as argument of this function, it gives a pointer toward the main function. So you have to set a breakpoint on this address  (`b*<addr_of_main>`) and to continue the execution by using the `continue` command.
Now that your are in the main function, wait that your programm call your method, if you can't enter in this function, you can modify your registers with :

```
set $<register>=<value>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your binary might be loaded with ASLR which is a security feature to make addresses to code and data unpredictable.

Try [disabling ASLR](http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2010/07/03/gdb-turns-off-aslr/) when you're in GDB - before loading the executable.

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
(gdb) start
```

Comment: I'm going to remove the PIE flag from the Mach-O headers and test.

Comment: I think the ASLR recommendation was a solid lead, but there is still a base address involved. I'm up voting you.

Comment: ASLR is disabled, problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Use `info file` and/or `info shared` to figure out the executable's load address or the actual entrypoint address.

```
(gdb) info file
Mac OS X executable:
        <...>/test, file type mach-o-le.
        Entry point: 0x00002104
        0x00001000 - 0x0002b000 is <...>/test
        <...>
```

Comment: I'll check this, but I believe that information is not available on stripped ARM binaries running on device.